# Nunit3.0 How to use onetimeteardown

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I am using Nunit 3.0 and my `[Setup]` and `[TearDown]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]` methods are in base class and base class is inherted by all test classes.

If I create a playlist from nunit with test cases from different classes or fixtures   the `[OneTimeTearDown]` is executed for each test class or each testfixture.

My `[OneTimeTearDown]` method sends test execution report via email but with the above mentioned issue it is sending multiple emails.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Could you edit the question to clarify the expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method to be executed only once per test run, put into a class with attribute `[SetUpFixture]`

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSuiteInit
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void Bye()
    {
    }
}
```

See [NUnit docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) for details